# How to choose singular or plural form from presence of \and in argument

Tags: macros, titles

I need a new command `\director` (similar to `author`) to write project's director names.
But I would like to write the word Director or Directors (if more than one) in front of the names. The easiest way is to use two commands `\director` and `\directors` but is it possible to use one command who detects the word `\and` into the argument and selects plural form.

An example:

`\director{John}` produces

Director: John

`\director{John and Paul}` produces

Directors: John, Paul

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a solution in the "old style":

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\def\director{\begingroup\def\and{and }\dodirector}
\def\dodirector#1{%
  \def\theargument{#1}\dodirectori#1\and\dodirector\endgroup}
\def\dodirectori#1\and#2\dodirector{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax % no \and
    Director: #1%
  \else
    Directors: \theargument
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\director{John}

\director{John \and Paul}

\end{document}
```

If only `and` is preferred, then a shorter code suffices

```
\def\director#1{\def\next{#1}\dodirector#1 and \dodirector}
\def\dodirector#1 and #2\dodirector{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax % no \and
    Director: \next
  \else
    Directors: \next
  \fi}
```

The input would be

```
\director{John}

\director{John and Paul}
```

---

A "new style" solution (with `expl3`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\director}{ m }
 {
  \ignasi_print_director:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ignasi_print_director:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ignasi_director_seq { \and } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ignasi_director_seq \l_ignasi_temp_tl
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_ignasi_director_seq
   { Director: ~ \tl_use:N \l_ignasi_temp_tl }
   {
    Directors: ~ \tl_use:N \l_ignasi_temp_tl
    \ignasi_andify:
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ignasi_andify:
 {
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_ignasi_director_seq \l_ignasi_temp_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ignasi_director_seq {, ~ ##1}
  % \seq_if_empty:NF \l_ignasi_director_seq {,} % uncomment for ", and" style
  \c_space_token and ~ \tl_use:N \l_ignasi_temp_tl
 }
\seq_new:N \l_ignasi_director_seq
\tl_new:N \l_ignasi_temp_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\director{John}

\director{John \and Paul}

\director{John \and Paul \and George}

\director{John \and Paul \and George \and Ringo}
\end{document}
```

This will output

> Director: John
>   Directors: John and  Paul
>   Directors: John, Paul and George
>   Directors: John, Paul, George and Ringo

Uncommenting the line in the last definition will add a comma before "and" in case of three or more directors (American style).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\IfSubStr` from the `xstring` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}%
\newcommand*{\director}[1]{\IfSubStr{#1}{ and }{Directors}{Director}: #1}%

\begin{document}
\director{John and Paul}

\director{John Rands}% Test having "and" as part of the name
\end{document}
```

I added a space around `and` to not use the plural for the case where `and` is part of a name, as in the second example.

Answer (score 4):

A completely different solution: Why not change the input to accept a comma-separated list of directors, check the size of the list and then use director or directors accordingly. For example:

```
\setup<....>
    [directors={John, Paul}]
```

or

```
\setdirectors[John, Paul]
```

**EDIT** Here is an example implementation in ConTeXt

```
\setuplabeltext[director={Director: }, directors={Directors: }]

\def\doshowdirectors  #1{#1\let\showdirectors\redoshowdirectors}
\def\redoshowdirectors#1{ and #1}

\startsetups print:directors
  \getcommacommandsize[\getvariable{document}{director}]
  \doifelse{\commalistsize}{1}
      {\labeltext{director}}
      {\labeltext{directors}}

  \let\showdirectors\doshowdirectors
  \processcommacommand[\getvariable{document}{director}]\showdirectors

\stopsetups

\setvariables
   [document]
   [set={\setups{print:directors}}]

\starttext

\setvariables
  [document]
  [director={John, Paul}]

\setvariables
  [document]
  [director={John}]

\stoptext
```

The advantage of a comma list processing is that it is much easier to change the behaviour depending on the number of directors (e.g., if you want a comma after the name if there are more than two directors).

Comment: This is rather incomplete.

Comment: @egreg: Rest is just a matter of simple comma list processing. I am adding a ConTeXt version of it.

Comment: Not everybody is acquainted with comma list processing in ConTeXt. :)

Comment: @egreg: I used ConTeXt just because I am more familiar with it. The implementation using `expl3` code will be similar.