# How to test if some command similar to \author is used in .tex file?

Tags: memoir, conditionals, titles

I want to modify `\maketitle` command in a new document class based in `memoir`. `\maketitle` command should include a new `\director` command similar to author. If this command is defined in text file, the word Director (or Directors) followed by director's name is included in title but if not defined, nothing should appear.

Next code is a combination of the answers in [How to count the number of authors of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59819/1952) and
[How to make a new command similar to \author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58528/1952).
With second answer project directors name is added to title with `\maketitle` command and with the first one, the word Director or Directors is selected according command `\and` appering in `\director` command.

The problem is how to test if command \director is not used in order to avoid 'Director'.
I know how to add a `\newif\director` but not where to set and use.

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\director}[1]{\gdef\@director{#1}}%
\newcommand{\@director}{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\director given}}
\addtoiargdef{\director}{%
  \begingroup\let\footnote\@gobble}{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}
    \renewcommand{\and}{\unskip, }
    \renewcommand{\andnext}{\unskip, }
    \renewcommand{\thanksmark}[1]{}
    \renewcommand{\thanksgap}[1]{}
    \protected@xdef\thedirector{#1}
  \endgroup\endgroup}
\newcommand{\predirector}[1]{\def\@bspredirector{#1}}
\newcommand{\postdirector}[1]{\def\@bspostdirector{#1}}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{%
  {\@bspredirector \@director \@bspostdirector}%
}
\predirector{\begin{center}
  \large \lineskip .5em%
    \printdirector\par
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postdirector{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}

\newcommand\testdirector{%
        \expandafter\tst@dir\@director\and\nil%
}
\def\tst@dir#1\and#2\nil{%
        \edef\test{#2}%
        \ifx\test\@empty Director\else Directors\fi%
}
\newcommand\printdirector{%
        {%
        \protected\def\and{and }%
        \large \testdirector\par}
        }
\makeatother

\title{A Title}
\author{An Author \and Another Author}
%\director{My Director \and My other Director}
%\director{My Director}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\director` seems to be optional, say

```
\let\@director\@empty
```

instead of

```
\newcommand{\@director}{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\director given}}
```

Then try

```
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{%
  \ifx\@director\@empty
  \else{\@bspredirector \@director \@bspostdirector}%
  \fi}
```

So, if a `\director` command has not been issued, the test will be true and the `\else` part will be skipped.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But could you explain me why you solution with `\let` and `\ifx...\@empty` works while David Carlisle's one with `\newcommand` doesn't? I imagin there is some difference between `\@empty` and 'nothing' (see David's answer) but I don't know it.

Comment: @Ignasi It would work if you said `\newcommand*{\@director}{}` (note the `*`): `\newcommand{\@director}{}` is equivalent to `\long\def\@director{}`, while `\@empty` is a non-`\long` macro. Besides, `\let` is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If `\director` is optional then you don't want

```
 \newcommand{\@director}{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\director given}}
```

you just want

```
 \newcommand{\@director}{}
```

Then (more or less) you don't need to test anything, just use `\@director` and it will be the author supplied name or nothing.  You may need to make it a bit more complicated depending what you want to do pre and post director in the default (empty) case. I wasn't clear on that. But you could for example make all three internal commands empty and make director define the pre and post commands to use some spacing. So again, no testing is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I didn't worked as expected. I need to test that `\@director` is 'nothing' in order to avoid executing `\predirector` which pints 'Director (or Directors)'. How can I test this 'nothing'?

Comment: Tou could use `\ifx\@empty` as in @egreg's answer but as I say you don't _need_ to test. You can define \@predirector to be empty {} and define \director to define \@directpr to the supplied name _and_ \@predirector to "director or directors: " then \@predirector\@director does the right thing in both cases