# What's the difference between these kinds of redefinitions?

Tags: macros, titles

Trying to implement an own `titlepage` style I am encountering a few problems.

Specifically I am trying to show the authors in a different style (the show case below is not restricted to `\author` but works as an example). The idea is to provide a drop in replacement for the `titlepage` (`\maketitle`) by reusing the `\author` macro.
I have it working but only for some use cases and I don't understand where the difference is.

The values from the cases A, B, C work with cases 1-3, but I can't get case 4 to work with case C (A & B work).
Although it seems reasonable to say the case 3 and case 4 seem to be the same..

What is the magic difference I can't see?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{Tabbing}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter

\def\tst@au#1\and#2\nil{%
    \edef\test{#2}%
    \ifx\test\@empty One \else More\fi%
}%

\newcommand{\@testAuthor}{%
    \expandafter\tst@au\@author\and\nil%
}

\newcommand{\@prettyPrintAuthor}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@author}{}}%
    {}%
    {%
        \@printAuthor%
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\@printAuthor}[0]{%
    \protected\def\and{\\ \> \>}%
    \begin{tabbing}%
        XXXX \= XXXX:XX \= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \= \kill%
        \> \@testAuthor: \> \@author%
    \end{tabbing}%
}%

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% case A
%\author{Title First Name}

% case B
%\author{Title First Name \and Title2 First2 Name2}

% case C
\author{\emph{Title} First Name \and \emph{Title2} First2 Name2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter

% case 1
\begin{tabbing}%
    XXXX \= XXXX:XX \= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \= \kill%
    \> More: \> \emph{Title} First Name \\ \> \> \emph{Title2} First2 Name2%
\end{tabbing}%

% case 2
\let\@temp@and\and
\renewcommand\and{\\ \> \>}
\begin{tabbing}%
    XXXX \= XXXX:XX \= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \= \kill%
    \> More: \> \emph{Title} First Name \and \emph{Title2} First2 Name2%
\end{tabbing}%
\let\and\@temp@and

% case 3
\protected\def\and{\\ \> \>}%
\begin{tabbing}%
    XXXX \= XXXX:XX \= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \= \kill%
    \> More: \> \emph{Title} First Name \and \emph{Title2} First2 Name2%
\end{tabbing}%

% case 4 - this does not work
%\@printAuthor

\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Using `\edef\test{#2}` when `#2` contains `\emph` is surely bound to give problems. Since you're redefining `\author` anyway, why not using it multiple times, each time adding to a container? Say `\def\author#1{\g@addto@macro\@authors{\@doauthor{#1}}}`, so that you can execute `\@authors` giving `\@doauthor` the meaning you prefer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is never safe to use `\edef` on unknown tokens in LaTeX use

```
\def\tst@au#1\and#2\nil{%
    \protected@edef\test{#2}%
    \ifx\test\@empty One \else More\fi%
}%
```

Comment: Great! I've been spnding hours to find the problem and got the answer within minutes. Thanks a lot! P.S.: The code with `edef` origins from: [How to count the number of authors of a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59807/how-to-count-the-number-of-authors-of-a-document)

Comment: @kromo it happens: http://xkcd.com/386/